# Switching user in multi-monitors setup resets to single monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, user-switching

When switching users on my Windows 7 computer, my multi-monitor setup returns to using a single monitor (the other turns black) and I have to switch back to using both screens manually. Is there any way to avoid this problem? I use a ATI Radeon HD 5700 video card.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually switching users or logging out and back in?  Have you tried setting up the monitors as one user, logging out, setting them up as the other user, and rebooting the machine?  It should be saving these settings separately.

I'll test this out myself in a bit, I think I have a similar video card kicking around here someplace.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel silly. While my video card driver wasn't badly outdated, there was a new driver released just last week. Installing it solved this problem. I guess I should have tested that solution before writing here... Thanks anyway :)